31 October skipped, why?
I expect the following code to write 31st October between 30th October and the 1st November.
My output skips the 31st.
Is it a bug? Do I misuse these functions?
I suppose I did something wrong, as I found no comment about such an existing bug.
(Using Ubuntu 24.04.1)
PS: I found my newbie myitake right before pushing "send." Publishing to help other newbies like me. I was expecting January to be indexed as the month 1 but it is month 0.
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    struct tm * NewDate;
    
    struct tm myDate;
    myDate.tm_mday = 30;
    myDate.tm_mon = 10;  
    myDate.tm_year = 2024;   // Date == April 6, 2014
    myDate.tm_hour = 23;
    myDate.tm_min = 59;
    myDate.tm_sec = 59;  
    
    time_t TimeStamp;
        
        
    while ( myDate.tm_min > 50 || myDate.tm_min < 5 )
    {
        printf( " %d/%d/%d_%02d:%02d \n", myDate.tm_mday, myDate.tm_mon, myDate.tm_year, myDate.tm_hour, myDate.tm_min );
        
        TimeStamp = mktime ( &myDate );
        
        TimeStamp +=100;
        
        NewDate = localtime ( &TimeStamp );
        
        myDate = *NewDate;
    }
    return 0;
}

Result:
:~/Essai$ gcc bug.c 
xx@xx:~/Essai$ ./a.out 
 30/10/2024_23:59 
 1/11/2024_00:01 
 1/11/2024_00:03 
 1/11/2024_00:04 

Expecting:
 30/10/2024_23:59 
 31/10/2024_00:01 
 31/10/2024_00:03 
 31/10/2024_00:04


Remove your solution from within your question and place it as an answer. That you found that your problem was caused by an error, you should probably delete this altogether.

You have myDate.tm_year = 2024;   // Date == April 6, 2014.  There are 2 problems in that line.  The year is encoded so that if tm_year == 0 is 1900, so the year represented by tm_year == 2024 is 3924, not 2014 or 2024.  And the date is not April 6, 2014.

The range of tm_mon is between 0-11 not 1-12. Month 10 is then November which only has 30 days, so the output is correct.
Using strftime() you can see that this is correct:
char buffer[255];
if (strftime(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%A %c", &myDate))
   printf("%s\n", buffer);

Reference:
struct tm

Incorrect initial use of struct tm
Code has at least these problems:
struct tm myDate;
myDate.tm_mday = 30;
myDate.tm_mon = 10;  
myDate.tm_year = 2024;
myDate.tm_hour = 23;
myDate.tm_min = 59;
myDate.tm_sec = 59;  

.tm_mon is the months since January.  So for October, use myDate.tm_mon = 10 - 1;
.tm_year is the years since 1900.  So for 2024, use myDate.tm_year = 2024 - 1900;
.tm_isdst is not set.  Use 1 for daylight time, 0 for standard time and -1 if unsure.*1
Incomplete initialization.  struct tm has at least 7 members that need initialization.  Code fails to assign at least .tm_isdst.  There may be more.
// struct tm myDate
struct tm myDate = { 0 };  // All members are set to 0.

Rather than assign later, initialize at object definition time.
struct tm myDate = { //
    .tm_mday = 30, .tm_mon = 10 - 1, .tm_year = 2024 - 1900, //
    .tm_hour = 23, .tm_min = 59, .tm_sec = 59, //
    .tm_isdst = -1 };
    // All other members initialized to zero.


*1 Interestingly for me, today is the longest day of the year: 25 hours.  Time goes, in hour steps: 12:00 AM DST, 1:00 AM DST, 2:00 AM DST, 2:00 AM Std, 3:00 AM Std, 4:00 AM Std, ... 23:00 PM Std,
